# Xlinker entry argument do not work in Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

Many years ago, I create an library, which executes code automatically, when loading into memory.

I use -Xlinker --init=_entry, where _entry is an symbol in my library. Part of Makefile code is attached below:

```
gcc -ggdb -fPIC -c ./cli2gui.c
gcc -ggdb -shared -Wl,-soname,cli2gui.so.0 -o cli2gui.so.0.1 ./cli2gui.o -Xlinker --init=_entry -lutil -ldl
```

Everything compiles, but when executing program linked to my library (or loading it dynamically), no _entry was executed. I checked this by setting breakpoint in gdb.

How to solve this - I mean how to made _entry executed every time my library was loaded into memory?

Comment: Make sure your library contains the symbol `_entry` (and not `entry`).

Comment: Isn't the linker option called `-init` (with a single dash)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC (and Clang) will handle the details for you, if you just add the [`__attribute__((constructor))` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html).  The function does not need to have an externally visible symbol, as the attribute tells the compiler and linker to add the address of the function to the init section, causing the dynamic linker (if linked dynamically) or C runtime (if linked statically) to execute the function before main().

A simple example:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int wrerr(const char *src)
{
    if (!src || !*src)
        return 0;

    const int   saved_errno = errno;
    const char *end = src;

    while (*end)
        end++;

    while (src < end) {
        ssize_t  n = write(STDERR_FILENO, src, (size_t)(end - src));
        if (n > 0) {
            src += n;
        } else
        if (n != -1) {
            errno = saved_errno;
            return EIO;
        } else {
            const int  retval = errno;
            errno = saved_errno;
            return retval;
        }
    }

    errno = saved_errno;
    return 0;
}

__attribute__((constructor))
static void my_init(void)
{
    wrerr("my_init() called\n");
}
```

To test, you can compile this either as an object file in another program, or you can compile it to a dynamic library and interpose it at run time:

```sh
gcc -Wall -fPIC example.c -shared -Wl,-soname,libexample.so -ldl -o libexample.so
LD_PRELOAD=./libexample.so date
```